# Counting dummy variables in tableau

Tags: python, variables, boolean, tableau-api

I have multiple columns that I created in python using get_dummies() to help clean my data. I would like to use these columns in tableau to represent how many of each item there are from each country.

This is a very simplified example of my dataset (I really have more like 60 countries and over a thousand items, some from multiple countries).

Image of example: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qod8P.png)

I used the dummy variable in python so that I could count the number of times each country is present but I don't want to look at each country individually. I'd like to look at them as a whole. I was wondering if there was a way to do something similar to using * to compare data.
I was thinking of something like this in a calculated field:
IF [country*] = 1 THEN COUNTD[item_id]
Tableau doesn't like that since it's using an aggregate and non-aggregate measure. Not to mention [country*] doesn't work.

Does anyone have any advice on how to work with this data? I'm at a bit of a loss

Comment: Don't share data or code as images, share them as text (preferably formatted nicely in your question)

Comment: Please elaborate your problem with sample output in terms of the data image shared.

Comment: You are not clear in explaining the problem.  Please state clearly what you have by presenting us your data structure and desired output with that example dataset.

Comment: In the image shared, item 004 relates to US whereas column related to US is 0? Is that an inadvertent mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pivoting the data](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.htm), then should be able to do what you want.